# How to limit a Backbone collection using a query?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Say I have a query implemented on my REST server which limits the number of items I get from a resource through a query string like `/items?startswith=Foo`.  How do I hook this up to backbone so that `Items` collection changes when a different query is specified in the browser.  Do I change the `url` parameter of the collection in response to a change in `input` and then `fetch`.  Not looking for anyone to write code for me; I am just new to Backbone need someone to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In official backbone documentation there is a note about this:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

`jQuery.ajax` options can also be passed directly as fetch options, so to fetch a specific page of a paginated collection: Documents.fetch({data: {page: 3}})

So you can use `data` attribute while fetching your `Items` collection like this:

```
Items.fetch({
    data: {
        startswith: "Foo"
    }
});
```

So you don't need to change your model `url` in this case

Happy backbone coding!

Comment: You may also want to pass `reset: true` in the `fetch` argument object, which will replace whatever was in the collection with whatever you are pulling down from the server with that new query.

Comment: Thanks! This helps alot, I am building up steam slowly but surely with bb.